# How to add custom GUI to Game Center to match the look and feel of the iphone game?

Tags: center, leaderboard

Does anyone has any idea how to create custom leaderboard and achievements view in game center
so that it matches the view of the original game..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no perfect complete answer for this. all that can be done is very nicely explained in the book http://www.apress.com/9781430235279

Do find the source code in its full description.. Go read enjoy .

Cheers

Comment: I know its very old question but I'm also want to create custom ui for game center leaderboard so just I want to know we can do it?